# Why is Ash ok with Goh catching so many pokemon at once?

Tags: pokemon

Isnt being a pokemon trainer about actually training pokemon and not about just catching random pokemon willy nilly?

It seems out of character for Ash to so apathetically not mind that Goh is essentially kidnapping Pokemon from thier natural habitats to simply fill his smartphones pokedex

Why is Ash perfectly fine with Goh catching so many Pokemon?

Comment: in pokemon journeys to me it seems out of character for Ash to just not care that gohs essentially being like team rocket and taking all the pokemon

Comment: Have you forgotten what the franchise's slogan is?

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. The entire premise of the show is that everyone is happy to randomly 'kidnap' monsters from the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Ash caught 30 Tauros and ever only used one of them. The other 29 got transported to Oak and are just running around there(and seem to be treated well). So would it really be out of character for Ash to be ok with Goh catching all those Pokémon? Also consider that he got more then 30 other Pokémon that are currently living at Professor Oak, some of them have been there for entire regions without a second though of Ash who when entering a new region (with the exception of Johto) only brings Pikachu with him.

Similarly Goh's Pokémon are kept at Cerise lab (with five of Ash his own Pokémon) where they are happy.

Also in the series first episode, he tried to catch a Pidgey/Spearow  "willy nilly". And his Pidgeotto, Krabby and Caterpie were caught  like a regular Pokémon trainer would do...by battling and throwing a Poké Ball.

So why would he (even be allowed to) criticize Goh's actions/motivations while he did it himself as well.